# Importing external bookmark (*.dat) file using ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, bookmarks

Does anyone know how to use ArcObjects (specifically ArcGIS Engine for me) to import a bookmark (saved as a .dat) that was created and saved externally using ArcMap?

I have an ArcGIS Engine application that uses the ControlsMapManageBookmarksCommandClass, but this does not have Load/Save options that the ArcMap bookmark control does.

I've searched all documentation and forums with no luck.

Comment: Right. All kinds of ways to use/update existing bookmarks within a document but no actual example on how to utilize saved bookmarks. The AOIBookmark supports the IPersisStream interface. For more info on implementing persistence go here: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/CPP_VB6_VBA_VCPP_Doc/COM/ExtendAO/Persistence.htm

Comment: You can also store the bookmarks in the *.MXD file, the bookmark commands works after you have loaded an MXD.

Answer (score 2):

It appears .dat files are structured storage files.  Google turns up lots on: [read structured storage c#](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=read+structured+storage+c%23).

```
private void LoadBookmarks()
{
    string path = @"C:\projects\forums\bookmarks.dat";
    if (StgIsStorageFile(path) == 0)
        Debug.Print("is structured storage");
    else
        Debug.Print("not a structured storage file");
}
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    static extern int StgIsStorageFile(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        string pwcsName);
```

Also see this question *[Is there any library to access OLE Structured Storage from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897328/is-there-any-library-to-access-ole-structured-storage-from-c)* on Stack Overflow.